# Symfony - Autoconfiguartion interface tag

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to add a tag to all classes which implement an interface:

```
$container
->registerForAutoconfiguration(SettingInterface::class)
->addTag('some.tag.name')
;
```

...but it does not work and debug:container --tag=some.tag.name is empty. If I register a service directly with a defined tag, it works perfectly, but this is quite uncomfortable :) Did I miss something in documentation: Can anyone help me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Might need to show a bit more code.  Specifically, where is your code being executed?  Here is a [working example using src/Kernel.php](https://github.com/cerad/zayso4/blob/master/src/Kernel.php).

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the party, but here's what worked for me:

You have to call `$container->registerForAutoconfiguration` in kernel's or bundle's `build()` method, not `process()` method of the kernel or compiler pass.